# Удаление элемента из списка питон

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Есть список из 30 одинаковых элементов. Пользователь вводит количество элементов которое нужно удалить из списка `s` и добавить в `b`.

Если пользователь вводит число большее 15, то индексы списка выходят за пределы (`list index out of range`), если меньше 15, все работает нормально. Пробовал удалять с помощью `pop` и `del`. При использовании `del [:cnt]` нельзя удалить все элементы списка, поэтому этот вариант не подходит.

```
s = [ i for i in '1' * 30]
b = []
cnt = int(input('введите кол-во элементов'))
for j in range(cnt):
    b.append(s[j])
    s.remove(s[j])
print(b)
```

Answer (score 2):

> 'При использовании del [:cnt] нельзя удалить все элементы списка, поэтому этот вариант не подходит'

почему же не подходит, вроде работает, вот практически ваш код только без цикла:

```
s = [ i for i in '1' * 30]
b = []
cnt = int(input('введите кол-во элементов: '))

b.extend(s[:cnt])
del s[:cnt]

print(f'{s = }')
print(f'{b = }')

>>> out
'''
введите кол-во элементов: 30
s = []
b = ['1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1', '1']
```

Answer (score 2):

Как было написано ранее, при удалении элемента из списка, список сдвигается к началу. В Вашем варианте вроде все нормально работает, т.к. элементы одинаковые, на самом деле при удалении нулевого элемента первый становится нулевым, второй первым. И при следующей итерации цикла Вы удаляете не первый, а второй элемент.

Для формирования начального списка Вы зря используете списковое включение, список можно создать простым повторением. И чтобы не использовать промежуточное звено для добавления элемента в новый список, проще использовать `pop`.

```
s = ['1'] * 30
b = []
cnt = int(input('введите кол-во элементов: '))
for i in range(cnt):
    b.append(s.pop(0))
print(f'{b = }')
print(f'{s = }')
```

либо же заменить вторую строку и цикл списковым включением

```
b = [s.pop(0) for i in range(cnt)]
```

Однако стоит отметить, что вариант без цикла работает в разы быстрее.

Answer (score 1):

При удалении элементы ведь сдвигаются к началу списка. Поэтому вам нужно удалять не `j`-й элемент, а просто нулевой. Нулевой элемент в этой схеме - это и есть очередной элемент списка после удаления предыдущего нулевого элемента и сдвига элементов к началу списка. Ну и я поменял данные, чтобы видно было номера элементов:

```py
s = list(map(str, range(1, 31))) # элементы от '1' до '30'
b = []
cnt = int(input('введите кол-во элементов'))
for j in range(cnt):
    b.append(s[0]) # <-- !!!
    s.remove(s[0]) # <-- !!!
print(b)
```

Пример ввода-вывода:

```
введите кол-во элементов 30
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']
```

Хотя цикл в этой задаче вообще не нужен, проще её сделать с помощью **срезов**:

```py
s = list(map(str, range(1, 31)))
cnt = int(input('введите кол-во элементов'))
b = s[:cnt]
s = s[cnt:]
print(f's = {s}')
print(f'b = {b}')
```

Пример ввода-вывода:

```
введите кол-во элементов 15
s = ['16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30']
b = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15']
```

Answer (score 0):

Поскольку сюда переадресовали с вопроса "Как удалить элементы списка прямым проходом":

```
l = [ i for i in range(20)]
i = iter(l)
try:
    while 1:
        if (x := next(i)) % 5 == 0:
            l.remove(x)
except:
    pass
print(l)
-->
[1, 2, 3, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12, 13, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
```

Comment: Первая строчка делается проще: `l = list(range(20))`