# наткнулся на проблему с циклом и удалением элемента списка. Все время удаляется не тот элемент, что нужен, а следующий

Tags: python

Перебираю элементы списка по свойству класса и пытаюсь его удалить, но все время удаляется лишь следующий элемент, не тот что мне нужен.

```
class Employee:
    def __init__(self, name, salary, on_vacation, is_good_employee):
        self.name = name
        self.salary = salary
        self.on_vacation = on_vacation
        self.is_good_employee = is_good_employee

    def get_info(self):
        print(f'У {self.name} ЗП в месяц {self.salary}. В отпуске? - {self.on_vacation}. Плохой сотрудник? - {self.is_good_employee}')


employee_list = [Employee('Павел', 40000, False, True), Employee('Дарья', 50000, True, True), Employee('Юрий', 70000, True, False), Employee('Василий', 100000, False, True), Employee('Федор', 170000, False, True)]


for employee in employee_list:
    employee.get_info()
    if employee.is_good_employee == False:
        employee_list.remove(employee)


print(employee_list)
```

Comment: Ну разве хорошо менять список во время итерации по нему? Есть несколько методов- например, обходить список с конца.

Comment: ``if employee.is_good_employee == False:`` нужно делать ``if not employee.is_good_employee:``

Comment: Жили-были баран да овца, 
Поставили они стожок сенца. 
Не начать ли сказку с конца?

Comment: Если, всё таки, нужно удалять прямым проходом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1426727/%d0%a3%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%8d%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%be%d0%bd/1538396#1538396